# How Go's interface programming model compares to OOP?

Tags: oop, go

I have read through most of the Go tour tutorial, but I'm still unclear on how Go's interface programming model compares with OOP?

Can someone explain how I can start 'thinking in Go'?

I'm confused how you can define an interface, and then create objects based on the interface?

Does Go implicitly create an concrete implementation for you during compile time?

Comment: What do you mean by "compares with OOP"? A type "implements" an interface by defining all the methods found in that interface, IIRC.

Comment: I see at least one down vote, but this is a question that could use a series of answers below. I work with OOP all the time, but wrapping my mind around Go for complex problems still took time and reading. So let the not-so-definitive insight follow.

Comment: [This article](http://nathany.com/good) is a very good introduction to Object-Oriented Design in Go.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems OOP usually tries to solve is Polymorphism or the the ability for two different classes to have instances that behave the same. Usually in OOP this is accomplished by using inheritance. A Base class defines a minimal interface that other classes extend. All of the subclasses of Base class can be used as a Base class.

Go does the same thing not by inheritance but using interfaces. An interface is a "description" of behaviour. It is up to the individual Types in Go to satisfy this description by implementing each of the methods described in the interface. If a Type does implement all the methods described in the interface then it automatically satisfies the interface and can be *cast* to that interface automatically by the compiler.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that given interface `foo` and implementations `a`, `b`, and `c`, the implementations can share functionality depending on the scope of that functionality. So `type c struct { b }` could inherit the method sets of `b` while adding additional ones and still fulfilling interface `foo`

Comment: Technically it's not inheritance it's composition using embedded structs. C doesn't inherit B's methods. It delegates those methods to an embedded instance of B which doesn't and can't know that C even exists.

Comment: exactly, well said and addresses the scope issues I meant to raise.

Answer (score 2):

Go's interface system is akin to [structural typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).  Consider a snippet of python code:

```
def foo(bar):
   bar.baz(5)
```

In this snippet we don't know what concrete type `bar` is but we can say that it must have a `baz` method which accepts a single `int` argument.  Note that when we're writing the class of `bar` we don't have to declare that we're implementing this 'interface' (having a `baz` method which takes an integer).  We just write a `baz` method which works correctly when called with a single `int` and we can pass an instance to the `foo` method.

Go works in a similar manner but everything is checked *at compile time*.  In Python if we pass our `foo` method an instance of a class which does not have a `baz` method we get a runtime exception.  In Go we would define an interface with the `baz` method and state in the type of `foo` that it takes an instance of that interface.  Now *any* type which has a `baz` method on a single `int` satisfies the type that `foo` requires.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional (Java) OO is about class hierarchies. You model your problem with classes, some abstract, some final and interfaces. Then you provide implementations.

Go lets you go the other way around: Start with concrete types and implement your logic. If a useful abstraction emerges or is required: Pack it into an interface and refactor your code to use this interface type.